# Save self-constructed data in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have to do an assignment and need some help. In the first step I have to create data.

I have to write a function that calculates the mean of a desired amount of normally distributed numbers and repeats this process for a desired number of repetitions.

The function should return only a single vector consisting solely of the calculated means.

So this is my code so far:

```
 meanulator <- function(x=1000){
  mean(rnorm(x))
  }

meanulator() #calculates means of random rnorm-numbers


meanulatorrep <- function(r=10) {
  for (i in 1:r) {
  x <- meanulator(x=1000)
  print(x)
  }
}

meanulatorrep() #repeats it

vec <- meanulatorrep(c(r=100))

vec <- c( meanulatorrep(r=10))
```

And this is the point I don't know how to work with the data. The final vector is just NULL(empty).

Comment: `meanulatorrep()` is not returning anything...

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to your for loop you could use `replicate` like this:

```
meanulatorrep <- function(r=10, x = 1000) {
   replicate(r, meanulator(x = x))
}

meanulatorrep()
# [1] -0.013763838 -0.005205456 -0.022675000  0.032995429  0.043952000  0.020025558 -0.059852671  0.010714884 -0.025530839
#[10]  0.009895310
meanulatorrep(r = 3)
#[1]  0.015299678 -0.003567159  0.036352255
meanulatorrep(r = 3, x = 5)
#[1]  0.1186618  0.2755995 -0.3906417
```

This also lets you specify `r` and `x` from within `meanulatorrep`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your meanulatorrep to save the values rather than print.

```
meanulatorrep <- function(r = 10) {
  x2 <- NULL

  for (i in 1:r) {
    x <- meanulator(x = 1000)
    x2[i] <- c(x)}

  return(x2)
}
```

So when you do `vec <- meanulatorrep(c(r=100))` it will save 100 values in the `vec` vector.